# Debian Eeepc distro on SD Card

Tags: debian, apt, sd-card, asus

Ok, I have the minimal version of [Debian Eeepc distro](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC) installed on my Asus Eeepc; The problem is, the HDD is only 4GB and it *will not* be able to install everything to run a desktop environment.

Is there a way I can keep that in the same HDD but the next apt-get install  I do (and so on) use the SD card? Even if I have to `startx` by hand (as in, I don't mind that login shell);

All I really need is a web-browser capable of running todays-age websites and a text editor for coding (vim is OK, though i have to find the help-key combo), if moving apt-get to SD card isn't an option.

Comment: check this answer as a hint: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96552/23721

Comment: @Serge Thanks - If nothing else that certainly solves the problem, though I'd like to keep the minimal installation and boot-stuff on the current HDD and just the next stuff be installed on the SD

Comment: I am not a fan of debian and flavors, so have no much experience. My preference is RHEL and Fedora. I usually use KVM with a raw disk image that matches the SD in size. Then I install all I need, make any settings, e.t.c, test it and then copy the image over to SD

Comment: I'd do that, except the SD card reader is ... on the machine that's having the problem :D points for effort though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt installs files in your `/` directory, so you can't let it install package on your SD card unless you want to move your whole `/` to the SD card.  But instead you can mount your SD card in `/usr` where most files of a package would be installed there (I checked on my system, it's size is about half of my `/`).

To do this, make sure your SD card have linux-compatible filesystem, for example, ext4.  Then mount your SD card, clear it and copy your `/usr` in to that:

(I'll pretend your SD card has an ext4 partition `/dev/sdb1`, and it's mounted at `/sdb`, change the commands as your need)

```
cp -r /usr/* /sdb
```

And then remount it at `/usr`:

```
umount /sdb
mount /dev/sdb1 /usr
```

And then add this line to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1              /usr          ext4      defaults              1      1
```

Reboot and see if there's any problem, use `mount` to check `/dev/sdb1` is mounted at `/usr`.

If there's no problem, you can remove the old content of user by using bind mount:

```
mkdir /mnt/work
# This command will mount your / at /mnt/work, but will not mount /dev/sdb at /mnt/work/usr
mount --bind / /mnt/work

# Do NOT type this as rm -rf /mnt/work/*, or it'll be the same as rm -rf /*
rm -rf /mnt/work/usr/*

# And then finish
umount /mnt/work
rmdir /mnt/work
```

It should work, don't delete your old `/usr` too quick, though. Test it for a while.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I'd achieve that? right now, it's mounted auto in /sdb

Comment: @MoshMage I updated my answer, try it

Comment: Thanks @Rio -- I ended up setting a LVM and added the sdcard to the LVM - i have now a wipping 14GB to work with xD [ill set this answer as correct though, as it does what I ask]